# make python stop until a mouse click

Tags: python, tkinter, pynput

I am making a script in in this function i need it to read the mouse position of a certain textbox. I want the script to stop just before the mouse position is read and assigned to a variable, and continue when the mouse is clicked.

Here is the code

```
def savemousepos():
    global mousepossaved
    global mousePosRead
    l = tk.Label(main, text='click on the textbox').pack()
    ##pause script here until mouse click##
    mousePosRead = mouse.position
    r = open("pysettings", "w+")
    r.write(str(mousePosRead))
    r.close()
    l = tk.Label(main, text='position was read and saved.').pack()
```

I have tried the `pynput` listener but a) I'm dumb and cant figure out how to use it. b) Python gets angry that the listener and `tkinter` are running at the same time(something about threads).

I'd love to have a solution that either uses built in things or `pynput`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to pause the script till mouse click?

Comment: so that i can move the cursor to the spot where i need the mouse position to be saved

Comment: Hmmmm, you could use `after()` method

Comment: Does the duplicate question help you find an answer? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866778/how-to-wait-for-a-mouse-click) one.

Comment: the other thread... kinda works? when i try just that code it works and stops the script, but when i try to implement it into my script it doesnt. im definitely doing something wrong. calling it in the savemousepos() function doesnt stop the function, even if its called by button press or not.

Comment: Maybe you can ask @martineau to reopen the question, if the duplicate is not what your looking for.

Comment: @CoolCloud: The OP would need to ask a new question containing their revised code.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_move(x, y):
    print('{0}'.format((x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        print('Position click = ', '{0}'.format((x, y)))
        return False

mouselistener = None
def mouseOn():
    if mouselistener == None:
        mouselistener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click, on_move=on_move)
        mouselistener.start()

while True:
    mouseOn()
```

OR:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_move(x, y):
    print('{0}'.format((x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        print("Position Click is:", '{0}'.format((x, y)))
        return False

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click, on_move=on_move) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Hope this helps.

In these 2 cases the script stops when the left click exists.

So that the script doesn't stop you can replace the return False with return True or just delete the line.

The first option is perhaps more useful within a script with another Listener or other processes.

The second option is more functional to run independently.

Comment: helpful, but doesnt solve the problem that when i try to run the listener within this function tkinter window freezes. maybe im missing something?

Comment: Post more information about the code. Are you using thread?

In the case of the second option you could perhaps place your function inside on_move or on_click, and it would be executed by listener.join()
you can try to put your function inside join():
with mouse.Listener ... ... ... as listener:
listener.join (your_function())


In the case of the first option you can try to connect your function inside mouseOn and it would be executed once when mouseOn was called.

Comment: If necessary, put the Listener inside a function, try using the option with mouseOn () ".start ()"

But without seeing the code, you can't know exactly what's going on ...